# ios SdWebImage image wont display when resize image using Thumbor third party

Tags: ios, iphone, resize, sdwebimage, thumbor

I am using [SdWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for displaying images in ImageView If I use image URL directly like http://52.74.11.56/photos/2015/07/1438154558488.jpg , SDWebImage is working perfect.

But I need to use [Thumbor](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor) as thumbnail service. But by using thumbor URL like below

```
        str_thumb_URL0 =@"http://thumb.dot-share.com/unsafe/1024x556/smart/http://52.74.11.56/photos/2015/07/1438154558488.jpg";
        [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str_thumb_URL0]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                                 completed:^(UIImage image, NSError error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {                                    
                                     NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                 }];
```

Xcode generate this error

> "Error Domain=SDWebImageErrorDomain Code=0 "Downloaded image has 0
>   pixels" UserInfo=0x7f8e35477360 {NSLocalizedDescription=Downloaded
>   image has 0 pixels}"

**Note**: Thumbor URL above is working in most of other WebImage libraries except [SdWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Please help me out of this problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with server hostname of image URL.

**The solution is:-**

You can fix this with a simple command:

> echo "127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts